# Installing XGBoost

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am trying use the XGBoost package, but I am having trouble installing it. I am following the installation guide 
here
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation. I have successfully built xgboost for OSX using

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```

However, when I try to install the python package in my terminal using this code

```
cd python-package; sudo python setup.py install
```

I get the error `python: command not found`. I am not sure why I get this error because I have python installed and I can run ipython notebooks. Python is install here on my computer `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`. Do I need to add a path in my bash_profile to access it? I don't understand why I can't use python from the command line.

Comment: What's the output when you type `python` in your command line?

Comment: Also, What do you get from running these?
`ls /usr/bin/python*` and `ls /usr/local/bin/python*`

Comment: When I type python in my home directory `cd ~; python` I get `bash: python: command not found`. Hmm yeah this might be the problem. When I run `ls /usr/bin/python*` I have a lot of different versions. When I run `ls /usr/local/bin/python*` I get `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I have answered similar issue in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988884/xgboost-install-error/45607243#45607243). You can install xgboost library along with other essential libraries as follows(please choose based on the libraries sufficient for your project), my main focus in this answer is to make it helpful in setting up for most data science projects requiring sklearn, pandas, scipy and xgboost algorithms along with visualization libraries.

```
# installing essentials
apt-get update; \
apt-get install -y \
  python python-pip \
  build-essential \
  python-dev \
  python-setuptools \
  python-matplotlib \
  libatlas-dev \
  curl \
  libatlas3gf-base && \
  apt-get clean

# upgrading pip
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
python get-pip.py && \
rm get-pip.py
# installing libraries
pip install numpy==1.13.1
pip install scipy
pip install -U scikit-learn
pip install seaborn
pip install --pre xgboost
```

If you're still having environment issues I would suggest using this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/datmo/xgboost/~/dockerfile/). You might also find Datmo conversion useful to facilitate this.

DISCLAIMER: I work at this company called [Datmo](https://beta.datmo.io/), which is building a community of developers by simplifying the machine learning workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `python` in your `/usr/bin/` directory, all you need to do is to add that directory to your path.

Add this line to your `.bash_profile` and restart your shell.

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"`

Then you should be able to use any of the python versions in your `/usr/bin` directory. `python`, `python3` etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I tried adding `/usr/bin/` to my path and for some reason the shell still can't find the python command.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ls /usr/bin/python*` and `ls /usr/local/bin/python*`? That'll help me understand which python versions you have, and the directory they reside in.